# Custom Metadata - default value does not apply to existing records

Tags: custom-metadata

**Problem**

I'm working with  `custom meta data` records. We have email subscription recipes for various contacts in the org.

The admins need to be able to add custom fields to these recipes without requesting a developer to update the code. I wrote the apex code to handle this scenario. However, `Checkbox` field types causing errors for existing metadata recipe records.

I noticed that the default value does not work. For example, on the custom records that already exist, the admin would have "re-save" the custom metadata records so that the field type value does not come through the trigger as a `null` value. This is because the `default values` for example, `unchecked` or `checked` do not carry over to the existing metadata records, and so when they run the trigger I get an error of "the data type is null and does not match the required field type".

**Question**

Is my only option here to `resave` all custom metadata type records? Or is there a configuration I'm missing when creating the custom field? Maybe there is a way to make the apex code handles this scenario?

Thanks for the help!

**Apex method**

```
public with sharing class RecipeMaker {
    public static Map<String, Contact_Subscription_Recipes__mdt> recipeValues = Contact_Subscription_Recipes__mdt.getAll();

public static void setRecipeValues(Contact c,  String recipeNumber){
    
    List<String> exceptionValues = new List<String>{'MasterLabel', 'Label', 'Language', 'QualifiedApiName', 'NamespacePrefix', 'DeveloperName', 'Id' };
    Map<String, Object > mapValues = Contact_Subscription_Recipes__mdt.getInstance('Recipe_' + recipeNumber).getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    Map<String, Object > fieldValues = new Map<String, Object>();
    
    for (String k : mapValues.keySet()){
        if (!exceptionValues.contains(k)){
    // build query
            System.debug('Field/Key = ' + k + '--> ' + 'value ' + mapValues.get(k));
        
            
            fieldValues.put(k, mapValues.get(k));
        }
    }
    
    
    for (String k : fieldValues.keySet()){
            Boolean f = false; 
            System.debug('Setting for update --> ' + k);
            c.put(k, fieldValues.get(k) );
            System.debug(c.get(k));
        }
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values are never applied to existing records. They are always set to an empty/null state. However, this seems surprising, because checkboxes cannot contain a null value. They are always checked or unchecked, and the default is to be not checked. That said, I think the easiest way to work around this problem is to describe each field, and if it has a DisplayType of BOOLEAN, then compare the field value to true. This would convert the nulls to false.

Here's a suggested update:

```
Map<String, sObjectField> contactFieldMap = sObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
for (String k : fieldValues.keySet()){
    if(contactFieldMap.get(k).getDescribe().getType() == DisplayType.BOOLEAN) {
        c.put(k, fieldValues.get(k) == true);
    } else {
        c.put(k, fieldValues.get(k) );
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Making records update like that would be a massive background whenever a field was added. I attempted your logic here prior to posting, but it did not work. I was just checking for null values and then updating the map to have a `false` value. But the value did not seem to take. I'll attempt again.

Comment: @thinker You can't put false in to any kind of field, which is why my design checks first if the field is a checkbox. If not a checkbox, we pass in whatever we are given, which may still be null.

Comment: They are all checkboxes. So it shouldn't really matter, right.

Comment: ah, I see you're using a contact field map